# data entered in the form using php is not sent to oracle database

Tags: php, oracle11g

Here are my connection code. when i run it it does not have any error but the data is not in the oracle database

```
<?php

// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('ART', 'system', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

?>
```

this is my register form code where user should enter their details and the details will enter the oracle database

```
<html>
<head>
<title>KHUNSTART</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="logo.png" type="image/x-icon">

<style>
a:link {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#ff0000;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active {
    color:#ff0000;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#border {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background: transparent;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="95%" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="black" align="right">

    <a href="loginform.php"><font face="Trebuchet MS" size="4" color="white">SIGN IN/REGISTER</font></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>

    <center><img src="LOGO PROJECT.png" width="20%"></center>
    <hr>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center">
    <font face="Trebuchet MS" size="4" color="black">
    <a href="index.php" >HOME</a> | 
    <a href="artist.php" >ARTIST</a> | 
    <a href="art.php" >GALLERY</a> |
    <a href="about.php" >ABOUT US</a> |
    <a href="contact.php" >CONTACT</a></td></font>
</tr>
</table>

<center>
<body>
<form name="buy" method="post" action="register0.php">
<table border="4" width="500">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">

        <font size="5" face="calibri">BE A MEMBER NOW</font><br>
        <font size="2" face="calibri">Be among the first to order our limited products!!<br>
        </font>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>Full Name</b><font color="red">*</font><br>
        <input type="text" name="cust_name" size="30" required>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>IC/Passport</b><font color="red">*</font> (IC/passport number without '-')<br>
        <input type="text" name="cust_ic" size="30" required>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>Address</b><font color="red">*</font><br>
        <input name="cust_address" type="text" size="30" required>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>Phone Number </b><font color="red">*</font>(Eg: 017*******)</font><br>
        <input name="cust_phone" type="text" size="20" required>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>Email</b><font color="red">*</font><br>
        <input name="cust_email" type="text" size="30" required>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>Username</b><font color="red">*</font></font><br>
        <input name="username" type="text" size="20" required>

        <br><br><font face="calibri">
        <b>Password</b><font color="red">*</font></font><br>
        <input name="password" type="password" size="20" required>

        <br><br><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset"><br><br>
        </td>



    </tr>
</center>   
</body>
</html>
```

this is my php code for the register form

```
<?php
/* include db connection file */
include 'dbconn.php';



if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    /* capture values from HTML form */
    $cust_ic = $_POST['cust_ic'];
    $cust_name = $_POST['cust_name'];
    $cust_address= $_POST['cust_address'];
    $cust_phone = $_POST['cust_phone'];
    $cust_email = $_POST['cust_email'];
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


        /* execute SQL INSERT command */
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES ('".$cust_ic."', '".$cust_name."', '".$cust_address."', '".$cust_phone."', '".$cust_email."','".$username."', '".$password."')";

        header("Location: loginform.php");

$compile = oci_parse($conn, $sql2);
oci_execute($compile);
}
?>
```

Comment: You do realize your code is incredibly insecure right?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you are simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong - you have no error handling, you don't check return values. And your query also assumes that the structure/ordering of the fields in your table will never change.

Comment: what should i do ? this coding i used to connect with mysql and it works. but when i try to connect with oracle i didnt work. i still cant find the wrong with this code. i hope anyone can explain to me more.

Comment: guys thnks you so much. the data can be enter now thank you so much !!!